# winform - refresh the other form while refreshing the initial

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I have `form1` and `form2`

```
private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//codes to display db
}
```

then I use `form2.ShowDialog();` to open the form because I dont want multiple windows

then in my form2 i have to delete something so the `form1` must update the display.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
//codes to delete
  form2_Load(sender, e); //so the form2 will reload
}
```

First I have to open first `form1` before I can open `form2`. How can I update/refresh the `form1` whilst still in form2?
EDIT:
The only thing I want to refresh in the `form1` is the `dataGridView`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [refresh a dataGridView from another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000463/refresh-a-datagridview-from-another-form)

Comment: Is the form2 can be opened without opening form1

Comment: btw, don't call an event handler such as `form2_Load(sender, e)` directly. You should write those stuff in a function, and call that function in `form2_Load` and `dataGridView1_CellContentClick`

Comment: @un-lucky no. form1 must be open first.

Comment: dont think in terms of controls being refreshed: refresh the datasource.  Then, there is no need to refresh that if they are using the same datasource

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not good idea to  update other form directly from the current form. It's better to design a **mediator** using delegate and callbacks to update other forms when your user is working in current and active form.

Comment: My `form1` is just use for queries and `form2` is more on technicals. So I think it's okay just to refresh/update the display

Answer (score -1):

This question depends on **Does `form2` know how to access `form1`?**

If so, you can call `form1.Refresh()` (or some other public method) to ask form1 update the list. (Of cause, you have to override the `Refresh` method, or create your own public method).

If not, maybe you can consider to use [Singleton pattern on your `form1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313646/can-i-make-a-form-a-singleton).

--

Moreover, if `form2` always created by `form1`, you can consider to open `form2` like this (must write in `form1`)

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Open(this);
//-- or
form2.OpenDialog(this);
```

If so, you can access `form1` in `form2` by calling `this.Parent`.

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you still have to ask questions, use comments.

Comment: @LucMorin I have update my answer, and I think this all problem can be solved by Singleton Pattern...